# Window freeze for single thread in while loop of Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am writing a short program to display cards in a round. I suspect that it is the length of the code which prevents the final 'OK' submit on P3 (the last player's submission) from executing properly: at which point the program *sometimes* will evaluate the winner and clear the round, but most of the time instead will freeze.
I have tried clock.tick(low fps), pygame.event.pump(), and pygame.event.clear(). Any leads would be much appreciated.

```
# Round loop begins. Finish until all hands are empty.
            while not self.game.get_is_last_round():

                player = self.game.get_player(self.game.get_player_turn())
                hand = player.order_hand(player.get_hand(),
                                         self.game.get_round_level(),
                                         self.game.get_round_trump_suit())
                ok_clicked_2 = False

                pygame.event.pump()
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        self.deal_running = False
                        self.is_running = False
                        pygame.display.quit()
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        play = player.get_play()
                        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed(num_buttons=3)
                        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                        # Used DeMorgan's law to resolve error
                        ok_clicked_2 = (OK1_X < pos[0] < OK1_X + B_W) and (OK1_Y < pos[1] < OK1_Y + B_H) and click[0]

                        b1, card = self.check_hand(pos, player)
                        b2, play_card = self.check_play(pos, player)
                        if b1:
                            hand.remove(card)
                            play.append(card)
                            player.set_play(
                                player.order_hand(play, self.game.get_round_level(),
                                                  self.game.get_round_trump_suit()))
                            player.set_hand(
                                player.order_hand(hand, self.game.get_round_level(),
                                                  self.game.get_round_trump_suit()))

                        if b2:
                            play.remove(play_card)
                            hand.append(play_card)
                            player.set_play(
                                player.order_hand(play, self.game.get_round_level(),
                                                  self.game.get_round_trump_suit()))
                            player.set_hand(player.order_hand(hand, self.game.get_round_level(),
                                                              self.game.get_round_trump_suit()))
                clock.tick(100)
                surface.blit(background, (0, 0))

                if len(self.game.get_player(0).get_hand()) == 25:
                    self.game.set_is_first_round(True)
                else:
                    self.game.set_is_first_round(False)

                if len(self.game.get_player(0).get_hand()) == 0:
                    self.game.set_is_last_round(True)
                else:
                    self.game.set_is_last_round(False)

                if self.game.get_play_in_turn() != NUM_PLAYERS:

                    pygame.event.pump()
                    clock.tick(100)

                    if len(hand) <= 1:
                        width = 0
                        x = (BG_WIDTH - CARD_WIDTH) // 2
                    elif len(hand) >= 8:
                        width = (BG_WIDTH - SIDE_W - CARD_WIDTH) // (len(hand) - 1)
                        x = BG_WIDTH // 2 - (CARD_WIDTH + (width * (len(hand) - 1))) // 2
                    else:
                        width = CARD_WIDTH
                        x = (BG_WIDTH - (CARD_WIDTH * len(hand))) // 2

                    surface.blit(background, (0, 0))

                    self.blit_backs()
                    self.blit_round()

                    self.show_ok()

                    self.show_hand(x, ROW3h, width, hand)
                    self.show_hand(CARD_POSITIONS[0][0], CARD_POSITIONS[0][1], SLIM_WIDTH, play)

                    if ok_clicked_2:
                        for card in play:
                            hand.append(card)

                        player.set_hand(player.order_hand(hand, self.game.get_round_level(),
                                                          self.game.get_round_trump_suit()))

                        # If player is first to start a round, he/she has a different validity check.
                        # (Sets the pattern for the cycle)

                        if player.get_begins_cycle():
                            valid = self.game.check_validity(True)  # is_first
                        else:
                            valid = self.game.check_validity(False)  # Is not first to play in the round

                        if not valid:  # Clear holding if invalid
                            if (play == []) or (player.get_play() == []):
                                print("\nYou must make a play.\n")
                            else:
                                print("Invalid play. Try again.")

                                if not player.get_begins_cycle():
                                    valid_plays = player.get_valid_plays(self.game.get_pattern(),
                                                                         self.game.get_round_trump_suit())
                                    print("Valid plays: \n")

                                    for temp_play_idx in range(len(valid_plays)):
                                        temp_play = valid_plays[temp_play_idx]
                                        print("[", end='')
                                        for temp_card_idx in range(len(temp_play)):
                                            valid_plays[temp_play_idx][temp_card_idx].show_card("", '')
                                            if temp_card_idx != len(temp_play) - 1:
                                                print(", ", end='')
                                        print("]")

                            # Clear the current player's selection and restore hand to its original content
                            cycle_order = self.game.get_cycle_order()
                            cycle = self.game.get_cycle()
                            for player_order in range(len(cycle_order)):
                                if player == cycle_order[player_order]:
                                    cycle_order.remove(player)
                                    cycle.pop()
                            self.game.set_cycle_order(cycle_order)
                            self.game.set_cycle(cycle)

                        else:  # Valid play on submit
                            # Special case for HIGH_SUIT play, play lowest card if another player has greater
                            play = self.game.check_high_suit(play)

                            # If friend card played, establish and print teammates
                            # TODO: auto-designate friends if the last round
                            #  has been reached (friends buried in treasure case)
                            # TODO: determine whether friend is "dead"
                            self.game.check_for_friends()

                            cycle = self.game.get_cycle()
                            cycle.append(play)
                            self.game.set_cycle(cycle)

                            cycle_order = self.game.get_cycle_order()
                            cycle_order.append(player)
                            self.game.set_cycle_order(cycle_order)

                            # self.clear_positions()

                            for card in play:
                                hand.remove(card)

                            player.set_hand(
                                player.order_hand(hand, self.game.get_round_level(),
                                                  self.game.get_round_trump_suit()))

                            self.game.next_player_turn()
                            self.game.set_play_in_turn(self.game.get_play_in_turn() + 1)
                            print(self.game.get_play_in_turn())

                        play = []

                else:
                    self.game.set_play_in_turn(0)
                    # Distribute any points in the round to round winner
                    self.update_cycle_points()
                    for p in self.game.get_players():
                        for card in p.get_play():
                            discard = self.game.get_discard()
                            discard.append(card)
                        p.set_play([])

                pygame.event.clear()
                clock.tick(100)
                pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here that's not necessarily relevant, nor is the code runnable. I think if you posted a [mre], it would be a lot easier for people to help out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's time for a code-cleanup, then your issue will go away (or you'll find it).

Currently the main loop is a big mix-up of event handling, screen-painting and game engine.  Try to separate these parts out.

Move some of the in-loop processing out to functions - like the block after `if ok_clicked_2:`.  It may help to make a data structure in which you store the game-state, then have the events change that game state.  When it comes time to draw the game to the screen, the painting code can query the state, acting accordingly.

In terms of your actual lockup, if `self.game.get_play_in_turn() == NUM_PLAYERS` nothing is painted to the screen.  Is this intentional?  Add some `print()`s to your code so you can know the execution flow (or learn to use the python debugger).

I think the biggest step forward would be to move all the screen painting to one section of the main loop, something like:

```
# Render the screen
print( "Rendering Screen" )
surface.blit(background, (0, 0))
self.blit_backs()
self.blit_round()
# etc. for all other things, score, buttons, ...
clock.tick(60)
pygame.display.update()
```

You seem to be handling the events OK, so it would probably be better to remove the calls to `pygame.event.pump()` and `pygame.event.clear()`.  You don't need these.

Answer (score 0):

Following Kingsley's advice, I organized the code by function: rendering screen, game engine, and event handling. I would provide MRE as Random Davis suggests, but that would include 5 integrated files which would take too long to pare down.

It turns out that the problem lay in a piece of code which is called separately: "update_cycle_points()". Within, there is a while loop which does not contain an event handler. The solution was to change it to a for loop, which Pygame seems to process without error (does not freeze because it does not expect event handling there).

I also removed pygame.event.clear() and pump() functions without problems.